# Is the following map homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let **$S^1$** the unit circle in **$R^2$** where **$R^2$** equipped by the discrete topology .

Let **$λ$** the identity map from **$S^1$** equipped by the discrete topology to **$S^1$** equipped by the discrete topology  .

Is **$λ$**  homeomorphism ?

Comment: It seems you are asking whether $id:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism, where $X$ denotes a topological space. Then the answer is of course "yes". Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since for any topological space $(X,\tau )$ the identity map $I:(X,\tau )\to (X,\tau )$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because your map is a bijection, because the domain is endowed with the discrete topology, making your map continuous, and because every subspace of a topological spaces endowed with the discrete topology also has the discrete topology, making the inverse of your map continuous.

Comment: Thank you  very much  sir